# Filter through an array of objects, javascript

Tags: javascript

I have created an array of objects, and function that loops through the array which creates html elements and populates them with values from the array, I have also appended them to existing tags on the html. Currently, I get a list on my page, but I want to use the input to filter through the array of object and display only the values that match the user input. PLease help??

```js
let internationalCountries = [
    {
        name: "Spain",
        method: "Delivery",
        price: "£10.99",
    },
    {
        name: "Germany",
        method: "Delivery",
        price: "£8.99",
    },
    {
        name: "Japan",
        method: "Delivery",
        price: "£39.99",
    },
]

let renderCountryList = () => {
    let list;
    let itemName = "";
    let para1;
    let para2;
    let method = "";
    let price = "";
    let ul = document.querySelector('.country-list')
    let deliveryInfo = document.querySelector('.delivery-info')
    for (let i = 0; i < internationalCountries.length; i++){
        list = document.createElement('li')
        itemName = document.createTextNode(internationalCountries[i].name)
        list.appendChild(itemName)
        ul.appendChild(list)
        para1 = document.createElement('p')
        para2 = document.createElement('p')
        method = document.createTextNode(internationalCountries[i].method)
        price = document.createTextNode(internationalCountries[i].price)
        para1.appendChild(method)
        para2.appendChild(price)
        deliveryInfo.appendChild(para1)
        deliveryInfo.appendChild(para2)
    }
}
renderCountryList()
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Search..." id="searchInput">
<div>
  <ul class="country-list">
  
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="delivery-info">

</div>
```

Comment: Add an event handler, use `.filter()` to get the elements that match the input, toggle the visibility of the elements in `.delivery-info` accordingly. Should be a fun task to do.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: @RashedRahat Don't add "check my answer" comments. OP gets a notification for answers. And begging for upvotes/accepted answers is not welcome here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

Visit to see live demo: [CODEPEN solution](https://codepen.io/rashedrahat/pen/xxgGPKG)

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search..." id="searchInput">
<div id="info-wrapper">
  <div>
    <ul class="country-list">

    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="delivery-info">

  </div>
</div>
```

```
const internationalCountries = [
    {
        name: "Spain",
        method: "Delivery",
        price: "£10.99",
    },
    {
        name: "Germany",
        method: "Delivery",
        price: "£8.99",
    },
    {
        name: "Japan",
        method: "Delivery",
        price: "£39.99",
    }
]

const backToStartStage = () => {
    let divSection = document.querySelector('#info-wrapper')
    divSection.innerHTML = '<div><ul class="country-list"></ul></div><div class="delivery-info"></div>'
}

const renderCountryList = (country) => {
    let list;
    let itemName = "";
    let para1;
    let para2;
    let method = "";
    let price = "";
    let ul = document.querySelector('.country-list')
    let deliveryInfo = document.querySelector('.delivery-info')
    
    list = document.createElement('li')
    itemName = document.createTextNode(country.name)
    list.appendChild(itemName)
    ul.appendChild(list)
    para1 = document.createElement('p')
    para2 = document.createElement('p')
    method = document.createTextNode(country.method)
    price = document.createTextNode(country.price)
    para1.appendChild(method)
    para2.appendChild(price)
    deliveryInfo.appendChild(para1)
    deliveryInfo.appendChild(para2)
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input#searchInput").keyup(function(){
    const input = $("input#searchInput").val();
    const found = internationalCountries.filter(country => {
      return country.name.toUpperCase() === input.toUpperCase()
    })
    if(found.length > 0) {
       backToStartStage()
       renderCountryList(found[0])
    } else {
      backToStartStage()
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add some smaple input for the input field and sample result in the list. Also, are you going to search by only country name or need some other configuration? Please add  those details as well.

If you want to search by only country name you can do the following,

```js
let internationalCountries = [
    {
        name: "Spain",
        method: "Delivery",
        price: "£10.99",
    },
    {
        name: "Germany",
        method: "Delivery",
        price: "£8.99",
    },
    {
        name: "Japan",
        method: "Delivery",
        price: "£39.99",
    },
]

let onChangeText = (e) => {
    renderCountryList(e.target.value);
}

document.querySelector('#searchInput').addEventListener('keyup', onChangeText);

let renderCountryList = (searchedName) => {
    let list;
    let itemName = "";
    let para1;
    let para2;
    let method = "";
    let price = "";
    let ul = document.querySelector('.country-list')
    let deliveryInfo = document.querySelector('.delivery-info')
    ul.innerHTML = null;
    deliveryInfo.innerHTML = null;
    
    res = searchedName ? internationalCountries.filter(item => item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchedName.toLowerCase()) > -1) : [...internationalCountries];
    for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++){
        list = document.createElement('li')
        itemName = document.createTextNode(res[i].name)
        list.appendChild(itemName)
        ul.appendChild(list)
        para1 = document.createElement('p')
        para2 = document.createElement('p')
        method = document.createTextNode(res[i].method)
        price = document.createTextNode(res[i].price)
        para1.appendChild(method)
        para2.appendChild(price)
        deliveryInfo.appendChild(para1)
        deliveryInfo.appendChild(para2)
    }
}
renderCountryList()
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Search..." id="searchInput" >
<div>
  <ul class="country-list">
  
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="delivery-info">

</div>
```

Comment: the input is already there on the html, yes search by country name, I get undefined when i run this code

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onkeyup()` method on your input element to call a function, in this case `printResults()` and pass the current value of the input element. The function then clears the contents of the `ul` and `div` and if the results of the filter function come back as an empty array then do nothing otherwise go into the `forEach` loop and iterate through the results.

**Note:** It's a good idea to break up your code into smaller functions, it helps readability and maintainability.

**Try this out:**

```js
let internationalCountries = [
    {
        name: "Spain",
        method: "Delivery",
        price: "£10.99",
    },
    {
        name: "Germany",
        method: "Delivery",
        price: "£8.99",
    },
    {
        name: "Japan",
        method: "Delivery",
        price: "£39.99",
    },
];

const filterData = (val) => {
  val = val.toLowerCase().trim();
  return internationalCountries.filter(item => item.name.toLowerCase() == val);
}

const printResults  = (val) => {
  let ul = document.querySelector('.country-list');
  let deliveryInfo = document.querySelector('.delivery-info');
  ul.innerHTML = "";
  deliveryInfo.innerHTML = "";
  
  let results = filterData(val);
  
  results.forEach((item, index) => {
    createListElement(ul, item.name);
    createP(deliveryInfo, item.method);
    createP(deliveryInfo, item.price);
  });
}

const createListElement = (ul, val) => {
  let list = document.createElement('li');
  let itemName = document.createTextNode(val);
  list.appendChild(itemName);
  ul.appendChild(list);
}

const createP = (div, val) => {
  let p = document.createElement('p');
  let text = document.createTextNode(val);
  p.appendChild(text);
  div.appendChild(p);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Search..." id="searchInput" value="" onkeyup="printResults(this.value)" />
<div>
  <ul class="country-list">
  
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="delivery-info">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make it simple like

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search by name, method or price" onkeyup="renderCountryList(this.value)" />
<ul class="country-list"></ul>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
let internationalCountries = [{name: "Spain",method: "Delivery",price: "£10.99"},{name: "Germany",method: "Delivery",price: "£8.99"},{name: "Japan",method: "Delivery",price: "£39.99"}];
const renderCountryList  = (val) => {
  let ul = document.querySelector('.country-list');
  ul.innerHTML = '';
  let results = internationalCountries.filter(({name, method, price}) => (name+method+price).toLowerCase().includes(val));
  results.forEach((item, index) => {
    ul.innerHTML += `<li>${item.name}<p>${item.method}</p><p>${item.price}</p></li>`;
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: This worked, but can you explain this line "let results = internationalCountries.filter(({name, method, price}) => (name+method+price).toLowerCase().includes(val));
  results.forEach((item, index) => {"

Comment: concating three column values  (name+method+price) and search in it. after that drawing values in their respective places